# Почему seleniumwire выдаёт ошибку OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', '', 'no start line')]?

Tags: python, selenium

Я просто создаю driver, но мне выдаёт ошибку OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', '', 'no start line')]
Вот код:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Почему так?